# How to add scroll on Windows Phone app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8 app on visual studio express 2012 for windows phone. I want to add vertical scroll function for contents inside `stackpanel` which is a series of text blocks.

I have attached a screenshot of where I want to add scrolling feature.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just a put it into a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use a `ScrollViewer`. Inside the ScrollViewer you can put your  `stackpanel`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add scrolling either add `Scrollview`(Best shown by Dave) or create a list..

But to me it looks like you are trying to create a List of data so You should be using List in place..

You can find sample below:

[XAML ListView and GridView essentials sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListViewSimple-d5fc27dd)

[How to add a list view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh943062.aspx)

Othee

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to scroll and how. If you have a simple list, then wrap your control(s) inside a `ScrollViewer` and it will automatically scroll.

Some containers already come with scrolling inside like `ItemsControl` such as `ListBox`, `LongListSelector`, etc.